# How do I wrap my text within a sliding navigation panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a panel that slides up and down when you click on it. When the panel slides down, some navigation text appears. When the panel slides up, the text is supposed to slide up with it, but it isn't. The panel slides and the text stays on the back. It hides but doesn't slide with the panel.

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
    <ul class="nav">
        <a href="#sec1" id="home">home</a>
        <a href="#sec2" id="proj">proj</a>
        <a href="#sec3" id="about">about</a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="flip"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a.panel').click(function() {
    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    current = $(this);

    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);

    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
#flip {
    content: url("Some image to click on");
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}

#panel {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.7;
    /* position:fixed;
    width: 100%; */
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, `a` is not valid content in `ul`, you've to wrap them with `li`s.

Comment: In addition to what @Teemu said, the class for 'selected' is not provided.

Comment: also `a.panel` doesn't exist. right

Comment: Sory dudes, I took the sample from here and modify a bit
view-source:http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, I don't know jQuery, but very quickly you could try and implement this via **CSS transitions**.

Once you have set the transition as

```
transition: property duration timing-function delay, property duration timing-function delay;
```

e.g.

```
transition: height 0.5s ease-in, opacity 0.25 ease-in 0.5s;
```

when you hover over the #panel (pseudo class :hover ), you can set different values for the #panel height and opacity.
Don't forget vendor-specific versions of the transition property (like -webkit-, -o- and so on).